# Phone Mugged while browsing

Tags: android, mobile

My phone (Samsung Galaxy note-4, model no SM-N 910U) mugged just couple of hours back while I was browsing in my car. Unfortunately, my location was turned off. I cannot locate it through Android device manager. My questions are:

1. I've sensitive personal information in the device so I gave the command to erase the data. Will it be effective?
2. The device was fingerprint locked. Since I was using it during the incident, will the erase be effective?
3. Is there any way to locate it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your phone's IMEI number ,it is still possible to track your phone. On the other hand if you have your sim card's serial number that's possible too. But the sim card might have been disposed of by now. 
Maybe this website could help you out , http://opencellid.org/

Your best option would be to approach the authorities and hope for the best. Sorry for your loss.

Comment: Thanks.  Giving command using android manager to erase the data,while the location service turned off in the phone ,will it effectively erase data?

Comment: I'm sorry but the phone will have to be connected a network for it to receive the command. Otherwise your data will probably not be deleted.

Comment: The device was finger print locked. Since I was using it during the incidence ,will it be effective?

Comment: The device was finger print locked. Since I was using it during the incidence ,will it be effective?
I mean, that remains as a last chance for me,( if they are not be able to hack the finger print lock)....my concern is that phone was open during the incidence...if it locks automatically after sometimes than they may not be able to open it easily....what is your opinion. Thanks a million.

Comment: Unless they're going after YOU specifically, rather than just "hey that guy has a nice phone and I want it," they're probably just going to factory reset and sell it. Or tear it down for parts.